# Why does 'HASH JOIN' or 'LOOP JOIN' improve this stored proc?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, optimization, join

I have a basic query that goes from 6 seconds to 1 second just by changing one join from `LEFT JOIN` to `LEFT HASH JOIN` or 'LEFT LOOP JOIN'.  Can anyone explain why this would cause such a large increase in performance and why SQL's optimizer isn't figuring it out on it's own?

Here is roughly what the SQL looks like:

```
SELECT
   a.[ID]
FROM
   [TableA] a
LEFT HASH JOIN
   [TableB] b
   ON b.[ID] = a.[TableB_ID]
JOIN
   [TableC] c
   ON c.[ID] = a.[TableC_ID]
WHERE
   a.[SomeDate] IS NULL AND
   a.[SomeStatus] IN ('X', 'Y', 'Z') AND
   c.[SomethingElse] = 'ABC'
```

Table A and B have millions of records and indexes on all the ID fields.  Using SQL Server 2005.

**Edit:** A collegue suggested a LEFT LOOP JOIN and it seems to have made it even faster...  SQL is not one of my strengths so I am trying to understand how these 'hints' are helping.

Comment: Could you please post the plan before the hint is applied and after that? Just issue `SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT ON GO SELECT …`

Comment: Remove all hints then run the query in SSMS with show actual plan, then in the plan compare the Estimated row count with the actual row count for the scan/seek operators at the edges of the plan. The plan is generated based on the *estimated* count, the duration is driven by the *actual* count. Discrepancies indicate bad stats, but can also happen with good stats for unusual, odd values (ie. the one SomeStatus that happen to have 1 mil. rows not 10).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`HASH JOIN` is useful when the large percent of rows contributes to the resultset.

In your case, building a `HASH TABLE` on either `A` or `B` and scanning another table is cheaper than either performing `NESTED LOOPS` over the index on `B.ID` or merging the sorted resultsets which the optimizer used before the hint.

`SQL Server`'s optimizer did not see that: probably because you didn't gather statistics, probably because your data distribution is skewed.

**Update:**

Since you mentioned that `LOOP JOIN` improved the speed, it may be so that the `JOIN` order was chosen incorrectly by the optimizer.

Comment: In this case almost all rows should left join successfully (eg. 90%+).

Comment: fixed s/distibution/distribution. Also: looks like you've finally passed me up for total votes on the sql-server stats page. I freely admit you're more knowledgeable on the topic, and so the world is now just a little less out-of-kilter.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=sql-server&sort=stats&pagesize=30

Comment: Thanks, you answer has helped me understand why this is occurring.