# Replacement for a Case statement

Tags: sql-server-2005, function, view, case

I have a function that works off of a view with two case statement.
The problem is that because of this case statement, it is taking 25+ seconds to run the function.  Where as it should only be taking ~3 seconds (comparing to an identical function with a view that doesnt call a case statement.)

The case statement is done within the select.

Interestingly enough(for me),  If I changed one of the case statements to something direct ie D.CARS instead of

```
CASE WHEN D.CAR IS NOT NULL 
THEN D.CAR              
ELSE C.CAR
END AS CAR,
```

Then it speeds up to ~3 seconds to run the function but shows some off results.  So it only seems to take~25 seconds if there is TWO case statements in the select statement.

The views regardless of number of case statements or not take less than 1 second to populate.

Is there a way to speed it up while still getting the correct results?

Comment: Have you tried adding computed columns to the view rather than invoking a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a `CASE` expression, why not use `COALESCE`?

```
COALESCE(D.CAR, C.CAR) AS CAR
```

Comment: I have never heard of the term. Let me give it a try.

EDIT - COALESCE seems to still give me the exact time result as the  CASE.  It is neater though.

Comment: If you run the query contained inside the function in Query Analyzer/Management Studio and look at the execution plan, where do you see the bottleneck?

Comment: 29 and 24% at two hash match inner joins and one 25% hash match on a right join.... which seems weird since i dont have right joins?

Comment: Without seeing your entire query (and/or the execution plan), it's kind of guesswork. SQL thinks you have a right join somehwere. You may need extra indexes on your tables, you may want to force a loop join by calling `INNER LOOP JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`, you may want to rework your function into an inline query, and so on...

Comment: Alright.  Calling the inner loop join did help it out significantly. Would you mind explaining to me what exactly the 'loop' is? I cant find it in sql server f1 help

Comment: The following links should explain it better than I could, or give you a good start:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395582/why-does-hash-join-or-loop-join-improve-this-stored-proc and http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/937/difference-between-hash-merge-and-loop-join

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using a function instead of a case statement?

Comment: Functions will almost always perform worse than an inline query; at the very least, no better.

Comment: The hit is negligible and it always improves the readability of the code. Imagine case statements like this reproduced across numerous SPs...

Comment: So you are saying I should have a function inside a view inside a function?  Never thought of that.  I will try it out.

Comment: Sorry, should clarify - the optimizer says it always performs worse. I have found no evidence it actually does. On the contrary in my experience.